# IntelliJ not resolving Play's build.sbt libraryDependencies

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt, sbt-idea

I am new to IntelliJ IDE and I am trying to use it for a new Play project I am working on. I have added some libraries to the libraryDependencies in **build.sbt** but IntelliJ cannot seem to resolve them as External Libraries

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.10.2",
  "org.webjars" % "angularjs" % "1.2.13",
  "org.webjars" % "foundation" % "5.1.1"
)
```

I am using the Play 2.0 Plugin for IntelliJ Ultimate and I also have the sbt and Scala plugins installed.

When I run the **play run** command from the command line everything compiles and works fine, but it is annoying seeing all the errors in the IDE:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run additionally

```
play idea
```

or

```
play "idea with-sources=yes"
```

And reload project when IntelliJ will ask for that

Comment: Thanks. I did run the command initially but not after I added the dependencies. Do I really have to run this every time I add a new library?

Comment: Yes, but it's not a problem as experienced, adding new libs occurres max once a several days. You can also add it manually in projects settings, but play command do it always without any errors

Answer (score 1):

If you're using IntelliJ 13 it has built in SBT support. You'll need to reimport your project (that is, delete the .idea folder, and then Import Project). From there you get a nice little menu on the right hand side and you can set it to autorefresh when the Build files change (or manually refresh).

The nice thing about SBT integration in IntelliJ is that it will preserve your other project settings, which I don't believe the play idea command does.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can just run the following command (when you are in play console) :

```
update
reload
```

Idea will detect some change and it will ask you to reload the project.